# How to properly change font height in Font Forge?

Tags: fontforge

When line-height in CSS is set to 1, my font vertically centered to lower letters.

[image]

When select letter

[image]

But I need center it to capitalized letters

[image]

Here is how it made in Roboto font

[image]

How to proper make it with Font Forge? I tried Element -> Transfomations and it works, but is it right way?

Answer (score 1):

I have not experimented with how metrics change the appearance of selection highlighting within browsers -- and it's not entirely clear from your question what you're trying to achieve. But here's my advice for setting up metrics, which should be a good place to begin understanding your precise issue: http://benwhitmore.altervista.org/line-spacing-getting-right/

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible by messing with the values in `Element` > `Font Info` > `OS/2` > `Metrics` - by default I think `Is Offset` is checked, but if you uncheck that, you can manually set each of the ascent/descent values. Each of the settings has hover text that explains what they do, but short of understanding those (I'm not entirely sure I do), experimenting might be the easiest way to figure things out.

Answer (score 0):

I had spent all morning looking for a tutorial for this. [Here is a YT video that might help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiylAy15ORI). I've figured that it's the ratio between the ascent and descent values that matters. In my case, the descent was 800 while the ascent was 2533 which was causing my font to be shifted more towards the top. When I reduced the descent to 600 and increased the ascent to 2733 (keeping the total same) with the instruction shared in the video, the font became much more centered visually.